# How to define a variable in .def file in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, make, gcc

I am working first time on def file in Linux, but don't know how to set a variable in def file.
i tried by below ways, but it's not working for me.

```
    **Test_DIR=/usr/include/
TEST_DIR_GCC_VERSION=$(shell gcc -dumpversion)
#define  TEST_LIB $(Test_DIR)/$(TEST_DIR_GCC_VERSION)**
```

in result i am getting only TEST_LIB=/usr/include,but not getting the entire variable path.

Any help will really appreciated, as struggling from last three days.

Comment: are you referring to the microsoft-compatible "def" format usable by `dlltool` in constructing windows DLLs?

Comment: I got def file in Linux, which is used by make file to set it variable. that's also file if you tell me how to set variable in microsoft-compatible "def".

Comment: file extensions are meaningless on unix, so if you refer to a file by extension then people have to just guess what you mean. So this "def" file is included by a Makefile? If so then it'd just be normal `make` syntax `var=value`

Comment: Yes this def file is included by a makefile, but all the flexibility of makefile are not working for def file.

Comment: the code block in your question looks nothing like `make` syntax to me, and if variables happen to be set in the main makefile after the inclusion the bindings there would be overridden